# How can i screenshare the second page in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to use the screenshare popup from chrome to screenshare the second page i did an approach in pyautogui but i'm trying to make it fully automate in selenium

I've tried these arguments

```
options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
options.add_argument("--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing")
options.add_argument("--allow-http-screen-capture")
```

But as expected it screenshares the whole screen but not the second page in selenium

Answer (score 0):

you can use the chromeMediaSource and chromeMediaSourceId options in Chrome's getUserMedia constraints

```
# Set the desired page/tab index to capture (0 for first, 1 for second, and so on)
page_index_to_capture = 1 

chrome_options.add_argument(f"--use-file-for-fake-video-capture={page_index_to_capture}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: That didn't really work, it does nothing